# Searching with multiple tables in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

I have this search query

```
 $products = Product::query()
            ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
            ->orWhere('slug', 'LIKE', "%{$search_any}%")
            ->where('status', 'Active')
            ->get();
```

i have user table which stores the user who listed the product and its relation is as follows

> Product Model:

```
  public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

I have one field `type` in user table, i want if user enters search string matches type also then also all the products added by them should be returned i was trying this code but how can i combine both the queries

```
 $products = Product::query()
                ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
                ->orWhere('slug', 'LIKE', "%{$search_any}%")
                ->where('status', 'Active')
                ->get();
 $productsAddedByUser = User::where('type', 'LIKE', "%{$search_any}%")->get();
// saved $productsAddedByUser result in this array $userIdarray
$productnew = Product::whereIn('user_id', $userIdarray)->get();
```

I want to combine both the results of `$productnew` and `$products`

Comment: At first save result in `$userIdarray` , then in products query,  add `->whereIn('user_id', $userIdarray)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first save result in `$userIdarray`, then in products query:

```
$userIdarray = User::where('type', 'LIKE', "%{$search_any}%")->pluck('id');

$products = Product::query()
    ->where(
        fn($query) => $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
            ->orWhere('slug', 'LIKE', "%{$search_any}%")
    )   
    ->where('status', 'Active')
    ->when(count($userIdarray), fn($query) => $query->whereIn('user_id', $userIdarray))        
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks if there is no matching with user id will it still return the first where i.e. name and slug

Comment: Nope, there should be at least one matching user_id otherwise empty array / null will be return.

Comment: But in my case if userIdarray is blank then also it should return result of first where and the same product should not get repeated because it can match with name and slug then again it can return the same product where it found matching user_id

Comment: Check updated answer.